# PS1 prompt to show elapsed time

Tags: bash, prompt

I currently use this to display the current time in my bash prompt:

```
PS1=\[\e[0;32m\]\t \W>\[\e[1;37m\]

20:42:23 ~>
```

Is it possible to display the elapsed time since the previous prompt?
Such as:

```
00:00:00 ~> sleep 10
00:00:10 ~> sleep 20
00:00:20 ~>
```

This has nothing in common with [Is it possible to change the PS1 periodically by a script in the background?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193635)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change the PS1 periodically by a script in the background?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193635/is-it-possible-to-change-the-ps1-periodically-by-a-script-in-the-background)

Comment: No, there is no answer in that post and I expect the prompt to change only when a new prompt is displayed.

Comment: There is not really a feasible way to do what you ask, no.

Comment: It's feasible if the displayed value is static (OP's question did not appear to allow that).  Elapsed time could be maintained by saving the epoch time of the previous time in a shell variable.  Implementing it seems a lot of work though (an hour or so -- perhaps someone will provide a simpler solution than what I have in mind).  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903239/how-to-calculate-time-difference-in-bash-script) would be helpful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way to do it would be to use the PROMPT_COMMAND feature of bash to execute code that modifies PS1. The function below is an updated version of my original submission; this one uses two fewer environment variables and prefixes them with "_PS1_" to try to avoid clobbering existing variables.

```
prompt_command() {
  _PS1_now=$(date +%s)
  PS1=$( printf "\[\e[0;32m\]%02d:%02d:%02d \W>\[\e[1;37m\] " \
           $((  ( _PS1_now - _PS1_lastcmd ) / 3600))         \
           $(( (( _PS1_now - _PS1_lastcmd ) % 3600) / 60 )) \
           $((  ( _PS1_now - _PS1_lastcmd ) % 60))           \
       )
  _PS1_lastcmd=$_PS1_now
}
PROMPT_COMMAND='prompt_command'
_PS1_lastcmd=$(date +%s)
```

Put that into your .bash_profile to get things started up.

Note that you have to type pretty quickly to get the `sleep` parameter to match the prompt parameter -- the time really is the difference between prompts, including the time it takes you to type the command.

```
00:00:02 ~> sleep 5   ## here I typed really quickly
00:00:05 ~> sleep 3   ## here I took about 2 seconds to enter the command
00:00:10 ~> sleep 30 ## more slow typing
00:01:35 ~>
```

### Late addition:

Based on @Cyrus' now-deleted answer, here is a version that does not clutter the environment with extra variables:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='
    _prompt(){
        PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND%-*}-$SECONDS))\""
        printf -v PS1 "\[\e[0;32m\]%02d:%02d:%02d \W>\[\e[1;37m\] " \
                      "$(($1/3600))" "$((($1%3600)/60))" "$(($1%60))"
    }; _prompt "$((SECONDS'"-$SECONDS))\""
```

### Extra late addition:

[Starting in bash version 4.2](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/commit/builtins/printf.def?id=495aee441b75276e38c75694ccb455bb6463fdb9) (`echo $BASH_VERSION`), you can avoid the external `date` calls with a new printf format string; replace the `$(date +%s)` pieces with `$(printf '%(%s)T' -1)`. [Starting in version 4.3](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/commit/builtins/printf.def?id=ac50fbac377e32b98d2de396f016ea81e8ee9961), you can omit the `-1` parameter to rely on the "no argument means *now*" behavior.

Comment: This is real close. It works when I copy/paste from a bash prompt, but when I tried to add it to my .bashrc it prints "1451424431: command not found"

Comment: maybe a little too much got copy/pasted?

Comment: This last version worked, exactly what I wanted! I think it had something to do with my trap to set the text color after the prompt. Thank you.

Comment: when you reset `$SECONDS` it ceases to track the time since the shell started,

Comment: @mikeserver - that's correct; if $SECONDS is something the OP wants for other purposes, then a temporary variable or two would be needed.

Comment: I do want seconds reset each time, I want to know the elapsed time for each command. Is it possible to use `trap` to reset seconds? This would remove the idle time from the calculation of the elapsed time.

Comment: I don't see a way to use `trap` to do this.

Comment: @mikeserv If you *unset* `SECONDS`, it ceases to be updated. You can, however, reset it to another value to have it increment from there. `SECONDS=0`, for instance, makes it useful as a timer.

Comment: @chepner - well, sure, but it doesn't keep the shell's time ever again. don't get me wrong - i upvoted this because it's a good answer - but i think that redefining an interactive shell's `$SECONDS` for every prompt is likely to elicit unexpected behaviors. any other shell function which might use it for any reason associated with evaluating run-time will misbehave.

Comment: I've updated the answer based on @mikeserv's point that $SECONDS may be useful elsewhere. I wanted to include it because I saw Cyrus post an answer using it (before deleting it), and thought it was a creative shortcut. I also took the opportunity to clean the code up a bit and also add a pointer to a recent bash printf feature.

Comment: @TeasingDart, I've updated the code to be a bit cleaner; my suggestion would be to use the updated code at the top that uses the `prompt_command` function, just in case you ever want to use $SECONDS for it's original purpose. Also, see the "Extra late addition" if you have bash versions >= 4.2.

Comment: @TeasingDart - yeah, you could use `trap`, too. for the idle time calculations you *could* start your timer in `$PS4` in `-x` trace mode, though, and only end it in the `$PS1`. it's probably more simple. but, for `trap`, you're just about guaranteed to get a `SIGCHLD` for every command run that matters *(which is to say - not just simple builtin-only simple commands)*. there is also `bash`'s DEBUG trap. and there is `$MAILPATH` - but i can't figure out what `bash`'s malfunction is about that one - it doesn't seem to do anything for it. POSIXly it should print a prompt for each modified path.

Comment: @Jeff: I prefer the previous version, with the function and lastcmd variable. It is easier to read and makes lastcmd available for other uses. When even my "embedded" system has a billion bytes of RAM, readability is more important than saving a few bytes.

Comment: @mikeserv: I tried a trap on every signal I could find, and they all happen *after* the process exits resulting in an elapsed time of 0. Even DEBUG, contrary to the docs, occurs after (not before) the process runs. -x mode is too ugly to use.

Comment: @TeasingDart - you have to handle `-x` w/ redirects. you have to manage the io. and yeah - they always happen after the process returns. so you start the clock in the PS4 - *(which is when you also trigger some logic to restore stderr so you don't have to look at it all the time)* and you stop it in the PS4 or your SIGCHLD trap or whatever. When you get your PS1 you let it print and redirect stderr > devnull, until you get your PS4 again. prompts really aren't about convenience - they're stream signals. interrupts. and *readability* is subjective - the shell is a macro language - it expands.

Comment: This answer is hard to follow with all the additions. What is the final, best version?

Comment: @mikemaccana No need to click through the revision history; the three snippets of code have different features: the first works, but adds _PS... variables to your shell environment; the second uses Cyrus' idea to avoid adding those shell variables; the third uses a newer bash feature to avoid the `$(date +%s)` calls that the first snippet uses. At the end of the day, I'd suggest using the code that's the easiest for you to understand & maintain (above & beyond whether you have bash 4.2+, of course).

Comment: @JeffSchaller I get that, and I've done the parsing needing to find the best answer but (eg with my own answers) I have a single section at the top with the best version first. Eg: 'Current version for bash 4.3 and up'. That would be useful here.

Answer (score 5):

```sh
PS1[3]=$SECONDS
PS1='${PS1[!(PS1[1]=!1&(PS1[3]=(PS1[2]=$SECONDS-${PS1[3]})/3600))
   ]#${PS1[3]%%*??}0}$((PS1[3]=(PS1[2]/60%60),  ${PS1[3]})):${PS1[1
   ]#${PS1[3]%%*??}0}$((PS1[3]=(PS1[2]%60),     ${PS1[3]})):${PS1[1
   ]#${PS1[3]%%*??}0}$((PS1[3]=(SECONDS),       ${PS1[3]})):'$PS1
```

This handles the formatting by calculation - so, while it does expand several times, it doesn't do any subshells or pipes.

It just treats `$PS1` as an array and uses the higher indices to store/calculate any/all necessary state between prompts. No other shell state is affected.

```
00:00:46:[mikeserv@desktop tmp]$
00:00:01:[mikeserv@desktop tmp]$
00:00:00:[mikeserv@desktop tmp]$
00:00:01:[mikeserv@desktop tmp]$
00:00:43:[mikeserv@desktop tmp]$ sleep 10
00:00:33:[mikeserv@desktop tmp]$ sleep 10
00:00:15:[mikeserv@desktop tmp]$
00:00:15:[mikeserv@desktop tmp]$
00:00:02:[mikeserv@desktop tmp]$
00:02:27:[mikeserv@desktop tmp]$
```

I can break it down a little maybe...

First, save the current value of `$SECONDS`:

```
PS1[3]=$SECONDS
```

Next, define `$PS1[0]` to be self-recursive in a way that will always set the right values to `$PS1[1-3]` while simultaneously self-referencing. To get this part you have to consider the order in which shell-math expressions are evaluated. Most importantly, shell-math is always the last order of business for shell-math. Before all else, the shell expands values. In this way you can reference an old-value for a shell-variable in a math expression after assigning it by using `$`.

Here is a simple example first:

```
x=10; echo "$(((x+=5)+$x+x))" "$x"
```

---

```
40 15
```

The shell will evaluate that statement by first substituting the value of `$x` wherever the `$` dollar-sign reference is used, and so the expression becomes:

```
(x+=5)+10+x
```

...then the shell adds 5 to the value of `$x` and afterward expands the whole expression to `x+10+x`, while retaining only the actually assigned value in the reference variable. And so the math expression's expanded value is 40, but the ultimate value of `$x` is 15.

That is largely how the `$PS1` equation works as well, except that there is a further level of math expansion/evaluation exploited in the array indices.

```
PS1='${PS1[!(PS1[1]=!1&(...))]#...}...'
```

I'm not really sure why I chose to use `PS1[1]=!1` there - I guess it was probably just silly aesthetics - but this assigns 0 to `$PS1[1]` while expanding it for parameter substitution. The value of a bitwise AND for 0 and anything else will always be 0, but it doesn't short-circuit as a boolean `&&` does when the left-most primary is 0 and so the parenthetical expression still gets evaluated every time. That is important, of course, because that first elipsis is where the initial values for `$PS1[2,3]` are set.

Anyway, `$PS1[1]` is here assured to be 0 even if it is tampered w/ between prompt draws. Within the parentheses there...

```
PS1[3]=(PS1[2]=$SECONDS-${PS1[3]})/3600
```

...`$PS1[2]` is assigned the difference of `$PS1[3]` and `$SECONDS`, and `$PS1[3]` is assigned the quotient of that value and 3600. All values are here initialized. And so:

```
${PS1[1]#${PS1[3]%%*??}0}
```

...if there are at least two digits in `$PS1[3]` then the inner expansion there is null, and because we know `$PS1[1]` is 0 then if `$PS1[3]` can be substituted away to nothing, so also is `$PS1[1]` else it is expanded to its value. In this way only single digit values for each iteration of `$PS1[3]` assignments will expand a leading zero, and `$PS1[3]` is itself expanded modulo 60 immediately thereafter while being concurrently assigned the next successively smaller value for each of hours, minutes, seconds.

Rinse and repeat, until the last iteration when `$PS1[3]` is overwritten w/ the current value of `$SECONDS` so that it may be compared to `$SECONDS` once more when the prompt is next drawn.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I found so far is this: https://github.com/jichu4n/bash-command-timer

Which prints `[ 1s011 | May 25 15:33:44 BST ]` aka the elapsed time on the right hand side after the executed command, so it doesn't clutter you PS1.

The whole string and time format is configurable. Even the color and the precision is configurable. I know it might be a bit much for some minimalist out there, but it's pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to solve this problem off-and-on for years, always frustrated by the variability of when PS1 is evaluated.  :-/

But today I found PS0, which is run immediately after you press 'enter' to run a command!

```
# Reformat seconds into days/hours/minutes/seconds:
function seconds2days() { awk -vtime="$1" 'BEGIN {days=int(time/86400);time-=days*86400;hours=int(time/3600);time-=hours*3600;minutes=int(time/60);time-=minutes*60;printf "%dd%02d:%02d:%02d\n",days,hours,minutes,time}'; }

# Find the age of a file in seconds (MacOS+Linux stat compatible):
function file_rel_age() {
  local now filetime
  now=$(date +%s)
  if ! filetime=$(stat -f%m "$1" 2>/dev/null || stat -c%Y "$1" 2>/dev/null ); then return 1; fi
  echo "($(seconds2days $(( now - filetime ))))"
}

# Passing the start time as the modification time of ~/.cmd.tty###:
_LAST_CMD_TIMESTAMP=~/.cmd.$(basename $(tty))
PS0="\$(date +%s > $_LAST_CMD_TIMESTAMP)"
PS1="\$(file_rel_age $_LAST_CMD_TIMESTAMP; rm -f $_LAST_CMD_TIMESTAMP )$ "
unset _LAST_CMD_TIMESTAMP
```

Nice properties: if you didn't run a command, it doesn't print a time, and the timestamp file is absent:

```
$ sleep 10
(0d00:00:10)$ vi /tmp/a
(0d00:00:03)$ ls -l .cmd*
-rw-rw-r--. 1 pfudd pfudd 11 Aug 12 17:07 .cmd.0
(0d00:00:00)$
```

Answer (score 0):

Eminently doable since Bash **4.4**, which introduced the `PS0` env var:

```bash
export PS0='$(date +%s%03N > ~/.execStart.$$)'

printElapsedCommandTime () {
    local execStart execEnd execDur elaStr
    if [ -e ~/.execStart.$$ ]; then
        read execStart < ~/.execStart.$$ 2>/dev/null
        rm -f ~/.execStart.$$
        if [ -n "$execStart" ]; then
            execEnd=`date +%s%03N`
            execDur=$((execEnd-execStart))
            printf -v elaStr "Ela %u.%03u" $((execDur / 1000)) $((execDur % 1000))
            printf "%*s\e[32;7m%s\e[0m\n" $((COLUMNS-${#elaStr})) "" "$elaStr"
        fi
    fi
}
export PROMPT_COMMAND='printElapsedCommandTime'
```

In `PS0` (displayed *after* Bash has read a command but *before* Bash has begun executing it) we save in a tempfile the output of `date +%s%03N`, which is Epoch seconds and the first 3 digits of nanoseconds: overall effect is to save Epoch microseconds.

In `PROMPT_COMMAND` (evaluated *after* Bash has finished executing a command but *before* Bash has displayed the primary prompt `PS1`) we find Epoch microseconds again, and from it we subtract our saved-in-tempfile measurement.

We show elapsed time on its own line, over on the right.  The lower `printf` is slightly tricky:

- Format specifier `%*s` consumes *two* arguments, an integer and a string; the former says how many columns to use up when printing the latter.  The two arguments we provide are N =  `$((COLUMNS-${#elaStr}))` and the empty string `""`; effect is to print N empty spaces.
- `\e[32;7m` requests inverse-video (“`7`”) text with green (“`32`”) background.
- `%s` is what consumes our `$elaStr` string.
- `\e[0m` resets font color to your normal.

---

Bash **5.0** introduced the `EPOCHREALTIME` env var, which obviates the two `date(1)` invocations. `EPOCHREALTIME` is fractional seconds with microsecond granularity; with `.` removed it is same as output of `date +%s%03N`, and so we obtain an improved solution with just two small changes:

```bash
export PS0='echo ${EPOCHREALTIME/./} > ~/.execStart.$$)'   ### change here...

printElapsedCommandTime () {
    local execStart execEnd execDur elaStr
    if [ -e ~/.execStart.$$ ]; then
        read execStart < ~/.execStart.$$ 2>/dev/null
        rm -f ~/.execStart.$$
        if [ -n "$execStart" ]; then
            execEnd=`${EPOCHREALTIME/./}                   ### ...and here
            execDur=$((execEnd-execStart))
            printf -v elaStr "Ela %u.%03u" $((execDur / 1000)) $((execDur % 1000))
            printf "%*s\e[32;7m%s\e[0m\n" $((COLUMNS-${#elaStr})) "" "$elaStr"
        fi
    fi
}
export PROMPT_COMMAND='printElapsedCommandTime'
```