# Show time elapsed since I started last command in prompt

Tags: bash, prompt

Is there a way to show time elapsed since I started last command? I found this: [PS1 prompt to show elapsed time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252229/ps1-prompt-to-show-elapsed-time) but that will show time elapsed since last command finished until the new command finished.

My idea is to somehow force the prompt to add `time`*before* every command I type in, and the format it in some nice way.

Something like this:

```
$ ls
. ..
Last command took 0.001s
$
```

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but zsh has some premade themes that do this easily (I use [powerlevel9k](https://github.com/bhilburn/powerlevel9k)). It's highly customisable, but can include duration of the last command. I highly recommend zsh over bash anyway for other reasons.

Comment: Is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/252229/117549 close to what you're asking?

Comment: @JeffSchaller It is the exact same question as I linked.

Comment: You want a time needed for the last command execution, do I understand it correctly?

Comment: @jimmij That is correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need two functions and a timer. First function is executed just after you hit enter on the command line, but before actual command starts. Second function is executed after command finishes, but before prompt is displayed. Timer just counts seconds since you start the shell. In `zsh` these three hooks are called `precmd`, `preexec` and `SECONDS` respectively.

In `bash` timer's name is the same, function `precmd` become a variable `PROMPT_COMMAND`, but unfortunately function `preexec` is missing, so you need to write it yourself (nothing extremely challenging, but not trivial either) or install already written hook from external source, e.g. https://github.com/rcaloras/bash-preexec.

Now we just need to glue all pieces together, minimal code looks like this:

```
preexec() {
    cmd_start="$SECONDS"
}

precmd() {
  local cmd_end="$SECONDS"
  elapsed=$((cmd_end-cmd_start))
  PS1="$elapsed "
}
```

Put everything in `.bashrc`.

Comment: I don't get it. Do you mean that I should manually type in precmd in front of every command?

Comment: @Broman Of course not, you define precmd and preexec once in .bashrc (or any init file) and these functions are treated specially by the shell. Before everything however install the script I linked.

Comment: I copied everything to .bashrc, commented out my old prompt, ran `source .bashrc` and restarted the terminal but my prompt does not show the execution time of last command.

Comment: What exactly did you put into .bashrc? In interactive bash run `curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rcaloras/bash-preexec/master/bash-preexec.sh -o ~/.bash-preexec.sh`, then `source ~/.bash-preexec.sh`, and then copy-paste two functions from my answer. Does that work?

Comment: Yes that worked. I did not understand that I needed to get the bash-preexec.sh. Thought it would be enough to copypaste preexec and precmd to .bashrc. However, I would like to include this number in my existing prompt. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: (I should have asked that in the question, but since I did not, I accept your answer. It's not what I want, but it is what I asked and you answered properly.)

Comment: Broman, to include this time to your existing prompt just change its value in the precmd, the time is stored in `elapsed` variable. For example `PS1="\u@\h $elapsed >"` will look more friendly. You can add colors or whatever you like, but all changes must be made inside precmd function.

Comment: Now I see it, and I feel a bit stupid. So obvious. Thank you very much.

Comment: I tried running this on GNU bash, version 5.0.17 and it appars that the `preexec()` is run within a subshell because setting variable 
`$cmd_start` doesn't appear to have visible effect in `precmd()`. However, I could use `SECONDS=0` as a workaround by resetting the Bash internal clock and use it as elapsed time as-is. BTW, is it possible to somehow get the return value of the last executed command so I could print it with the elapsed time? `$?` didn't seem to work inside `precmd()`.